# Call to a member function first() on array laravel 5.4

Tags: arrays, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I am very to new to laravel 5.4 and don't know about much about the blade template.

The issue is I am passing the array to the views and trying to get the first index of array element through the provided `first()` function of blade template but it's giving me error `Call to a member function first() on array`

Here is my controller code

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request )
 {               
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => 
        $request->input('password'), 'Status' => 0])) 
        {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('Users');
        }
    else
    {
        $json=array('email'=>'You cant leave Email field empty');         
        return  View::make('Auth/login')->with('error',($json));           
    }
 }
```

Here is my View Code

```
  @if($errors->any())         
       {{ $errors->first('email') }}
  @endif
```

I am looking for the solution which can exactly suit my needs. If am doing something wrong please correct me.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your approach you are not using Laravel validations. You just passing an array and basic php arrays does not have methods such as `any` or `first`. they belong to Laravel collections.

It is just an array and you can reach array elements as I explained below

so if you wanna keep your code you can do this

```
@if(isset($error))
   {{$error['email'] }} 
@endif
```

But correct way to do is for validation part;

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required| email',
    ]);
```

please read documentation deeply about validations and authentication https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
@foreach ($errors as $error)
   {{ $error }}
@endforeach
```

So you can see the list of the error returned

Comment: Yes mate I can use this but know why the code written above is not working?

Comment: I think function first is for eloquent use in laravel to return single in record